# Definition of cusp or corner

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I've seen many times the terms like "cusp" and "corner" in the calculus books but I want a formal and rigorous definition for it . I know $f(x) = |x^2 - 1|$ has a cusp at  $x = 1$ but I'm in doubt about $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2}$ at $x= 0$ .

Answer (score 3):

At an elementary stage, when one talks about a cusp or a corner of a curve $h(t)$ at $x_0$, it would mean that:

$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x_0+t)-h(x_o)}{t} $ doesn't exist and in particular it is different when $t$ approaches $0$ from the left and from the right.

It is customary to talk of cusps to curves that are otherwise smooth (infinitely differentiable) and while continuous at $x_0$ they have a *singularity*.

As Arnaud Mortier noted in the comments, in more sophisticated settings (e.g. algebraic or differential geometry) cusp has a more complex and precise definition.

Comment: I would want to include the condition that $h(t)$ be continuous at $x_0$ to eliminate jump discontinuities and poles.

Comment: You are right, I edited to include that. Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this is right - at least in differential geometry / knot theory we would not say that the curve $x\mapsto |x|$ has a cusp at $0$ for example.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  You are right, but I am assuming that the o.p. is asking for the definition of "cusp" or "corner" in an elementary manner (because of the mention of calclulus books) and therefore gave an answer I feel fits this level.

Comment: @NickA. Ah, maybe my bad then, I was not aware that there was an elementary and broader definition like that. Do you have any reference/calculus book with that terminology?

Comment: Edit: I see. I think that what you wrote is the common definition of a *corner* (had overlooked this part of the question first). But a cusp is really something different (at least I've never seen the word used in the sense of corner).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Exactly.  I gave my answer in an intuitive  and starting level since the question was about "cusps" and "corners". I am vaguely aware that in the more advanced settings that you mentioned there is more specific definition. Maybe you should add them as an answer  :)!

Comment: @NickA. It's ok then :). I can't remove the downvote unless you edit your post though. Ps: I did answer, although I forgot to take into account the intended level of the question like you did.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The example that you give, of the curve $y^3=x^2$, corresponds to what is called a *regular cusp* or *ordinary cusp*, in the sense that it is the least degenerate from the point of view of singularity theory. This leads us to:

**Definition 1 (used by some authors):** a cusp is precisely a point where a curve is equivalent to $y^3=x^2$ via a smooth local change of variables.

**Definition 2 (more general):** A piecewise smooth curve in, say, a euclidean space:
$$f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
 has a cusp at a point $p=f(x)$ if there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f$ is differentiable on both intervals $(x-\varepsilon, x)$ and $(x, x+\varepsilon)$, and if $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f_1'(x-h)=\lim_{h\to 0^+} f_1'(x+h)$$
where $f_1'$ denotes the **unit** tangent vector to the curve.

In words, the curve leaves the point in the same direction as it has reached it.